# Azure function V4 Service Bus, How to manually deadletter?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, .net-6.0

We've recently started upgrading our existing functions Version 3 to dotnet6 and azure functions version 4.

After a fair amount of googling I'm having hard time finding out if it's still possible to manually deadletter a service bus message in version 4?

I can see why complete was removed (pretty sure I had some documentation on this I can no longer find) but I imagine I might want to deadletter a message right away.

to further my question.
In V3 we could do use messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(lockToken) with a service bus message but in Version 4 I'm not sure if this option is still available.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to complete the queue too, I assume it should look like the following but 
it is not working. the queue still deliver till it reach max.


// create a receiver that we can use to receive the message
ServiceBusReceiver receiver = client.CreateReceiver(QueueName);
_ = receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(servbusMessage);